# Add textbox to chart using EPPlus

Tags: c#, excel, charts, textfield, epplus

I have an application where I create an Excel file with an variable amount of sheets and I know the sheetnames only during runtime.

Therefore I create my Charts during runtime. So far so good, I can create my Charts and modify them as needed but I can't manage to add additional textboxes or shapes within the chart(https://i.stack.imgur.com/UL2RI.png , I can't attach the picture directly).
I managed to add a normal TextBox to the file but I can't get it to be in the chart.

I searched the web but I am not sure if this is even possible with EPPlus.

Has anyone encountered a similiar problem?

Comment: You mention in your post, there is some kind of misplacement with epplus and excel.. I am trying to help you get answers. If you feel my comment is unecessary just ignore it. Please read the link i provided above and try and refactor your question. I am sure there is sth to refactor.

Comment: I believe you are referring to `UserShapes` for the chart: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/documentformat.openxml.drawing.charts.usershapes?view=openxml-2.8.1.  AFAIK  Epplus does not support them unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

I have created a textbox within the chart by using epplus c#, but I can't this textbox position out of the XAsix, please use this code ---

```
var tb1 = Worksheet4.Drawings.AddShape("tb1", eShapeStyle.Rect);
tb1.Text = "‘ASSUMES $100 INVESTED ON SEP. 30, 2017" + Environment.NewLine + " ASSUMES DIVIDEND REINVESTED" + Environment.NewLine +"FISCAL YEAR ENDING SEP. 30, 2022’";
tb1.SetPosition(32, 0, 5, 0);
tb1.SetSize(300, 100);
string fontColor = "#808080";
tb1.Font.Color = fontColor.ConvertToColor();
tb1.Font.SetFromFont("Calibri", 9, true, false, false, false);

tb1.TextAlignment = eTextAlignment.Center;
tb1.Fill.Color = Color.White;
tb1.Border.Width = 0;
```